# Inputs and its attributes are constantly changing in Dynamic x-path in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I tried to find the x-path of a text field *username* and *password*, but it keeps on changing dynamically.I won't be able to use `starts-with` or `contains` in a findelement using x-path. Here's the HTML DOM-

```
      <div id="contents">
          <h1 style="white-space:pre; width:80px; float:left;line-height:35px;">Login</h1>
          <span style="float:left; padding-top:13px; COLOR:#990033; font-weight:bold;">  Student | Parent | Faculty</span>
          <div class="form-elements">
          <div class="form-elements">
          <div class="form-elements">
              <div class="label-txt">Password</div>
              <input id="rcnr2uew1m0rkikeaaniwk" type="password" style="display:none;" name="rcnr2uew1m0rkikeaaniwk"/>
              <input id="ko2xs123ebqyoluh15bulu" type="password" style="display:none;" name="ko2xs123ebqyoluh15bulu"/>
              <input id="cuouek4bfz41etm4hroj0r" type="password" style="display:none;" name="cuouek4bfz41etm4hroj0r"/>
              <input id="u2ta3gv2o2ce0azx5plpuh" type="password" name="u2ta3gv2o2ce0azx5plpuh"/>
              <input id="g03nwjuzhqnkuwgsl4q2mu" type="password" style="display:none;" name="g03nwjuzhqnkuwgsl4q2mu"/>
              <input id="gddwv4z3amojk0yvoxi2v4" type="password" style="display:none;" name="gddwv4z3amojk0yvoxi2v4"/>
              <input id="kxecmkho2vf1vcfb42icjr" type="password" style="display:none;" name="kxecmkho2vf1vcfb42icjr"/>
              <span id="ctl04" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">*</span>
         </div>
```

I tried to find the input[4] with no style.

Absolute x-path- **html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input[4]**

Next time how it changes-

Absolute x-path- **html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input[17]**

`id` and `name` of the `input` also keeps on changing without any common trait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by locating sibling of the `User name` label that is displayed, i.e. without attribute `style="display:none;"`

User Name

```
"//div[contains(text(), 'User Name')]/following-sibling::input[not(@style='display:none;')]"
```

Password

```
"//div[contains(text(), 'Password')]/following-sibling::input[not(@style='display:none;')]"
```

Comment: Thanks, if _style_ attribute is not missing then how could i approach the problem

Comment: @bot13 You can check for specific attribute `not(@style='display:none;')`. Edited in my answer as well.

Comment: I meant if _style_ attribute is present for username as well then what could be the approach because then all inputs have same address

Comment: @bot13 `not(@style='display:none;')` is looking for an element that doesn't have `style` attribute `display:none`. If the `style` attribute was anything else, for example `block`, this `xpath` will find it.

Answer (score 0):

Or something similar using `type` attribute:

```
//input[@type='password'][not(@style)]
```